# asp MVC3 Wizard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an application with MVC3. This application shold contain a 4-step wizard. The user should be able to navigate to the next page and back without loosing the datas the user enterd.
I've seen something about creating a class for each step an just changing the display style. 
Is that realy the best way? 
And what about the people who do not have Javascript?

lot of thanks,
HW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need a component for ASP.NET MVC, I usually check what is available with JQuery, and there is a choice of third parties wizards on [their website](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/wizard). [JQWizard](http://www.techbuji.com/jqwizard/) seems to me really lightweight, which is something I prefer, but you should check the other based on your criterias.

Now for the people who do not have javascript activated, you could handle your wizard as a single page form without the steps. Or just disable the form with a warning "works only with javascript activated", if you don't feel comfortable with having a second way to input data in your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely implement it without using Java Script, but is that really a constraint now a days?

What you can try doing is create a object to hold all the responses from the different wizard pages and have POST actions to redirect the user between different action methods (you could add type  elements, one for forward and one for back.)

You can use the built in model binding system to have MVC 3 update the appropriate sections (corresponding to the different wizard pages) in the data object automatically for you.

Or, you could use the TempData[] dictionary to store the object during the POST or redirect.

However, still recommend that you implement a more Web 2.0 way and do it using jQuery/CSS.